# Run Python script from VBA: Run time 91. Object variable ... not set

Tags: python, vba

The script works. I want to call it from VBA passing two variables, the URL and file name.

I get

> run time 91. Object variable or With block variable not set

in the shell line.

This is the URL containing the table to download:
https://jde.erpref.com/?schema=920&table=F4311

This is my VBA code:

```vb
Sub Dw_table()
    
    Dim url As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    Dim objShell As Object
      
    
    ' Prompt the user to enter the URL and file name
    url = InputBox("Enter the URL of the table:")
    file_name = InputBox("Enter the file name:")

     'paths for exe and script
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\Mario    Rdz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\Mario Rdz\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\JDEREF.py"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript & url & file_name
    
End Sub
```

This is my Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl
import sys

# Passed arguments from excel VBA
url = sys.argv[1]
file_name = sys.argv[2]`

page = requests.get(url)

#Parse the HTML content of the webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

#Find the table with the ID "columnselectcollection"
table = soup.find(id="columnselectcollection")

#Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
your text`workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

#Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

#Set the values for column headers
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = "Seq"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=3).value = "Field"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=4).value = "Description"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=5).value = "Data type"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=6).value = "Edit Type type"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=7).value = "Lenght"
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=8).value = "Decimals"


#Iterate over the rows of the table and write the data to the worksheet
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = []
    for cell in row.find_all('td'):
        row_data.append(cell.text)
    worksheet.append(row_data)

#delete row 2 which is blanks and delete unuseful column 9
worksheet.delete_cols(9)
worksheet.delete_rows(2)

#Save the workbook to an Excel file
workbook.save(f"{file_name}.xlsx")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? See also: [ask]. For one thing, you need to put the exact error message your get into the question post.

Comment: What does the error message say? By the way, `Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String` isn't a shortcut for `Dim PythonExe As String, PythonScript As String`. Instead, it is implicitly the same as `Dim PythonExe As Variant, PythonScript As String`. Arguably this is a design flaw in VBA, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks john,,  I changed the definitions.

Comment: The error is :   run time  91.  Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: You declared `Dim objShell As Object` but nowhere `Set` that variable to be equal to a shell object. You are trying to use an unitialized object variable. You need something like `Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`.